# MutationObserver on class value

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I want to detect changes to a class='value' and take actions automatically.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="s3upload form-active">

<!-- after the form is submitted, 
     an external lib changes the class to: -->
<div class="s3upload link-active">
```

---

The code below runs without throwing errors. But it fires both *if* statements... so it cancels itself out.

Ideally, I would be able to narrow the mutation down to the specific values of the class attribute: "s3upload form-active" "s3upload link-active"

**JS:**

```
// node to observe
const picLink = $('.s3upload')[0];

const observer = new MutationObserver(function
    (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {

            // mutations to check for:
            if (mutation.attributeName === 'class') {
                console.log(mutation.type), console.log("active");
                $('#saver').css('display', 'block');
            }
            if (mutation.oldValue) {
                console.log(mutation.type), console.log("removed");
                $('#saver').css('display', 'none');
            }
        })
    }
)

observer.observe(
    picLink, 
    {
        // things related to picLink to watch for changes
        attributes: true, 
        attributeFilter: ['class'],
        childList: false, 
        characterData: true,
        attributeOldValue: true
    }
)
```

---

I've been following these docs/ tuts

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hn2zzi_lquA

Comment: attributeName will always be `class` since you've specified it in observe's parameters, but as for a specific value you'll have to check it manually using standard string functions - MutationObserver doesn't support that.

Comment: @wOxxOm ah, okay. so i will put some jquery in that first if statement. thanks.